# Как можно ускорить этот код Python?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, олимпиада

**Решаю задачу, но она не проходит все тесты по времени. Как я могу ускорить код?**

*В детском саду готовятся к новому году, и воспитательница решила организовать детей, чтобы они подготовили украшения и отправили их Санте Клаусу для украшения своих оленей.*
*Дети с интересом восприняли идею и вырезали из бумаги a звездочек и b снежинок. Теперь они планируют отправить их Санте Клаусу по почте. Им так понравились вырезанные ими украшения, что они, возможно, решат оставить себе часть. Таким образом, дети могут отправить Санте x звездочек и y снежинок, где 0≤x≤a и 0≤y≤b. Чтобы Санта не расстроился, дети должны отправить ему хотя бы одно украшение. То есть должно выполняться также условие x+y>0.
Чтобы все олени выглядели красиво, на каждом должно оказаться одинаковое количество украшений. Известно, что у Санты n оленей, поэтому если будут отправлены x звездочек и y снежинок, величина x+y должна делиться на n.
Воспитательница заинтересовалась: а сколько есть всего различных способов составить посылку Санте Клаусу. Два способа считаются различными, если в них отличается количество звездочек или количество снежинок.*

> Входные данные

В одном наборе входных данных содержатся несколько тестов. Каждый тест следует решить независимо.
Первая строка входных данных содержит целое число t — количество тестов (1≤t≤105).
Следующие строки описывают тесты, по одному на строке. Описание теста состоит из трех целых чисел n, a и b — количество оленей у Санты, количество звездочек и количество снежинок, вырезанных детьми (4≤n≤109; 0≤a,b≤109).

> Выходные данные

Выведите t чисел. Для каждого теста выведите одно число: количество способов составить посылку для Санты Клауса.*

```
amount_of_tests = int(input())
for i in range(amount_of_tests):
    test = input().split()
    deers = int(test[0])
    stars = int(test[1])
    snows = int(test[2])
    x = deers
    result = 0
    all_deers = [deers]
    while True:
        if deers + x <= (stars + snows):
            deers+=x
            all_deers.append(deers)
        else:
            break
    for item in all_deers:
        num1 = item
        num2 = 0
        for i in range(item+1):
            if num1 <= stars and num2 <= snows:
                result +=1
            num1-=1
            num2+=1
    print(result)
```

Comment: Такие задачи нужно решать аналитически, а не перебором.

Comment: Я аналитически смог дойти только до этого перебора))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f(x, y)` - единица если `x + y` делится на `n` и ноль иначе.

`f` периодична по `x` и по `y`:

> ```
> f(x + n, y) = f(x, y) - периодичность по x
> f(x, y + n) = f(x, y) - периодичность по y
> ```

У `f` интересные суммы по периодам (по полоскам размеров `n*1` и `1*n`):

> ```
> sum(f(x, y), x` <= x < x` + n, y = y`) = 1
> sum(f(x, y), x = x`, y` <= y < y` + n) = 1
> ```

У `f` интересные суммы по прямоугольникам размеров `n*b` и `a*n` (складываем предыдущие уравнения):

> ```
> sum(f(x, y), x` <= x < x` + n, y` <= y < y` + b) = b
> sum(f(x, y), x` <= x < x` + a, y` <= y < y` + n) = a
> ```

Обозначим `g(a, b) = sum(f(x, y), 0 <= x < a, 0 <= y < b)`.

Аргументы `a`, `b` можно сделать меньше `n`:

> ```
> g(a, b) = g(a % n, b) + g(a // n, b) = g(a % n, b) + (a // n) * b
> g(a, b) = g(a, b % n) + g(a, b // n) = g(a, b % n) + (b // n) * a
> ```

Как вычислить `g(a, b)` если `a, b < n`? В этом случае

> ```
> g(a, b) = 0        , если a = 0 или b = 0
> g(a, b) = 1        , если a > 0, b > 0 и a + b <= n
> g(a, b) = a + b - n, если a > 0, b > 0 и a + b > n
> ```

Число вариантов которое мы ищем равно `g(a + 1, b + 1) - 1` - наша функция сверху ограничена строгими неравенствами и считает один лишний вариант - оба нуля.

```
def g(n, a, b):
    if a >= n:
        return g(n, a % n, b) + (a // n) * b
    if b >= n:
        return g(n, a, b % n) + (b // n) * a
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return 0
    if a + b <= n:
        return 1
    return a + b - n


def h(n, a, b):
    return g(n, a + 1, b + 1) - 1


def main():
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        n, a, b = map(int, input().split())
        print(h(n, a, b))


main()
```

Рекурсия в функции `g` не настоящая. Её можно раскрыть так:

```
def g(n, a, b):
    s = (a // n) * b
    a %= n

    s += (b // n) * a
    b %= n

    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return s
    if a + b <= n:
        return s + 1
    return s + a + b - n
```

**P.S.** на [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/gym/103533/problem/5) предыдущее решение не проходит по времени. Причина перемежающийся ввод/вывод. Это вариант набирает 100 баллов:

```
def read_tasks():
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        yield tuple(map(int, input().split()))


def main():
    for n, a, b in tuple(read_tasks()):
        print(h(n, a, b))
```

Comment: Ваше решение пока самое произодительное! Прошло на 70 из 100 баллов. Не прошла по скорости лишь последняя группа тестов.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: https://codeforces.com/gym/103533/problem/5

Comment: @Bitchdragon, дополнил ответ. Порядок ввода/вывода влияет на время работы, что не красит Codeforces.

Answer (score 6):

Давайте подумаем... Итак,

```
x+y = n*k
```

при этом  k > 0 (условие x+y>0). Итак, к лежит в диапазоне

```
1..(a+b)//n
```

В цикле по этому диапазону (не забыть +1 из-за того, что верхняя граница в `range` не включается), прикинем, сколько же вариантов может быть...

x может быть от 0 до `min(kn,a)`, y — 0 до `min(mn,b)`. C учетом того, что `x+y == nk`, получается, что `kn` украшений можно получить `min(kn,a) +min(kn,b)-nk+1` способом.

Осталось просуммировать эти значения для всех `k` из указанного выше диапазона.

Поскольку писал со скоростью набора текста, добавлю-ка своё
*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*